# What's the best way to get input value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I was practicing with React and found two ways to get input values when submitting form.

**First:**
Using hooks, for example:

```
...
const [name, setName] = useState('');
...
return <input onChange={(value) => setName(value)} value={name} />
```

**Second:**
Get by using event.target.children[i].value, for example:

```
const handleSubmit = (event: BaseSyntheticEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formInputs = event.target.children;

        for (const input in formInputs) {
            console.log(formInputs[input].value);
        }
    };
```

The question is, which one should I use and why? Is it optional, or I don't know, it does have some performance impact.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Just want to get the input value, but I have these two options, now I'm curious about understanding which one is best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use vanilla DOM manipulation in React when you can avoid it, within reason. The first approach is far better in most situations.

- Working with the DOM is *slow*. State and the virtual DOM help a lot.
- In the React paradigm, the appearance and functionality of the application should ideally stem *from state* as much as possible. Non-stateful side-effects can make things difficult to reason about and hard to work with given how re-rendering works and should be avoided.

If the reason you're tempted to go with the second approach is that you have a whole lot of inputs and making a separate state for each is tedious, one option is to make the state be a single object (or Map) instead.

```
const MyInput = ({ name, state, onChange }) => (
  <Input name={name} onChange={onChange} value={state[name]} />
);
```

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
};
```

```
<MyInput name="name" state={state} onChange={onChange}/>
```